# Animation Nodes - bake sound, bake spectrum, evaluate sound

Tags: animation-nodes, audio

I make this node tree using "bake sound" mainly. 
I hope it helps, I have been investigating the possibilities offered by this node and some possibilities of use.

The first time we need to bake a sound, with these nodes it is possible to establish the number of frequency ranges, and the values ​​that comprise them. In this case I choose 9 intervals, configured by default and bake the spectrum data. This may take several seconds

[image]

Later, insert evaluate. If we debug this node, we can view the array data of any of the frequency intervals:

[image]

To get all the frequency data, we will need to add a node (*get list element*) for each interval. In my case I used this node tree to move an icosphere around the blender space, this icosphere gets a paticle system who emits metaballs to shape this movement (and I modified the damping).

[image]

This gray node uses it as a converter, the float controls the proportion of the movement. Later, we combine the data in a vector.

[image]

To interact with the metaballs particle system (to add modifiers, etc etc.), we translate the mesh to another object.

To view the node tree results go to this video 
https://youtu.be/q1z6DxcDDIk
thanks!! enjoy :)

[image]

Comment: Is this supposed the be a tutorial or a question? This site is focused on questions and answers, so a tutorial should be posted elsewhere. If it is a question can you make it clear what you are actually asking?

Comment: tutorial, i dont know how i may post it :_(

Comment: Recommend: Edit the question to make above the answer.